# How can I add scrim to text on an image?

Tags: html, css, format

I downloaded a webpage template off html5up which has pieces that look like this:

```
   <div id="main">
   <article class="thumb">
   <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
   <h2>Research Interests</h2>
   <p>I have some text here that I want to have the scrim background.
   </p>
   </article>
   </div>
```

(It's the multiverse template.)
I want to add a scrim to the text like the one [here](https://travishorn.com/responsive-scrim-6f286da5b6a5). I added the code:

```
.scrim {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

to my main.css file, but I cannot figure out how to correctly implement this in the html file.

Edit: This is the relevant existing code from the main.css file.

```
                        h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
                        color: inherit;
                        text-decoration: none;
                }

        h1 {
                font-size: 2em;
        }

        h2 {
                font-size: 1.25em;
        }

        h3 {
                font-size: 1.1em;
        }

        h4 {
                font-size: 1em;
        }

        h5 {
                font-size: 0.9em;
        }

        h6 {
                font-size: 0.7em;
        }
```

(then a lot of other stuff then)

```
.poptrox-popup .caption h2, .poptrox-popup .caption h3, .poptrox-popup .caption h4, .poptrox-popup .caption h5, .poptrox-popup .caption h6 {
                                margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
                        }
```

Comment: Arre you asking how to put the text on top of the img? Is there any more CSS related to any of those elements you show?

Comment: The text is correctly on top of the images, but with the images I chose the text can be hard to read, so I would like to add a scrim. I am using the default main.css file from the html5up aside from the addition I've included; I am not sure what parts are relevant (since I do not know any CSS). I would past it here, but it is very long. I cannot even figure out which part of the main.css file formats the text on top of the images.

Comment: You can find out what CSS is actually being used on each of the elements by going into your browser's dev tools inspect facility and looking at each element. However, I don't understand why adding the class="scrim" to the p element isn't doing what you want. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have, and it does not seem to be working (as in, it has no effect). (Also, I did manage to find the formatting for text in the pop up thank you.)

Comment: As you have found the CSS that is relevant to the elements you show please use it to make a runnable snippet which shows the problem you have with scrim not working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ```h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
font-size: 1em;
}

h3 {
font-size: 1.1em;
}

h4 {
font-size: 1em;
}

h5 {
font-size: 1em;
}

h6 {
font-size: 1em;
}.poptrox-popup .caption h2, .poptrox-popup .caption h3, .poptrox-popup .caption h4, .poptrox-popup .caption h5, .poptrox-popup .caption h6 {
margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}

.poptrox-popup .caption p {
color: #ffffff;
}
``` is where the text is formatted, should I be calling scrim in the css file?

Comment: Please put code into your question. You can edit the question to do this.

Comment: I see! I have tried to only include the relevant details in my edit.